# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in PySimpleGUI trying to assign variables depending on the values of Combo boxes

Tags: python, spyder, pysimplegui

This is for a school project and the idea is to choose options from four combo boxes and depending on what the inputs from the combo boxes are (which to my understanding value[0] would be the input from combo box 1, value[1] the input from combo box 2, etc.) I will assign a certain letter or number to the according variable (stelle_1 for value[0], stelle_2 for value[1], etc.) and when all inputs are put in and you press on 'Produkt anzeigen' you get the letters/numbers put together, which is what the programme is supposed to work like.
Unfortunately I get the Type Error ''NoneType' object is not subscriptable' for the 'if values[0] == "hell":' line (if I cross that line out I get it for the next if values[1] etc.' line) and I don't really know how to fix that. I've understood that it has something to do with values being a NoneType object and not a list, but I don't understand why it's working anyway and how I would go about fixing it.

Here's my code (I don't know there's no indented block, but everything after the while repeat line should be indented) :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("LightBrown13")


layout = [[[sg.Text(("Hautton"), expand_x=True), sg.Text(("Unterton"), expand_x=True), sg.Text(("Hautbild"), expand_x=True), sg.Text(("Finish"), expand_x=True)], 
       [sg.Combo(('hell', 'mittel', 'dunkel'), readonly=True, expand_x=True),
       sg.Combo(('kühl', 'neutral', 'warm'), readonly=True, expand_x=True),
       sg.Combo(('normal', 'fettig', 'trocken'), readonly=True, expand_x=True),
       sg.Combo(('glossy', 'matt'), readonly=True, expand_x=True)],
       [sg.Button(("Produkt anzeigen"), expand_x=True, expand_y=True)]]]

window1 = sg.Window('Foundation Finder', layout, size=(1250,100), keep_on_top=True)


repeat = "Erneut durchführen"
while repeat == "Erneut durchführen": 

event, values = window1.read()


if values[0] == "hell":
    stelle_1 = "H"
    merkmal_hautton = "hell"
elif values[0] == "mittel": 
    stelle_1 = "M"
    merkmal_hautton = "mittel"
elif values[0] == "dunkel":
    stelle_1 = "A"
    merkmal_hautton = "dunkel"
else: 
    stelle_1 = "undefined"
    merkmal_hautton = stelle_1
if values[1] == "kühl":
    stelle_2 = "B"
    merkmal_unterton = "kühl"
elif values[1] == "neutral":
    stelle_2 = "C"
    merkmal_unterton = "neutral"
elif values[1] == "warm":
    stelle_2 = "D"
    merkmal_unterton = "warm"
else:
    stelle_2 = "undefined"
    merkmal_unterton = stelle_2
if values[2] == "normal":
    stelle_3 = "1"
    merkmal_hautbild = "normal"
elif values[2] == "fettig":
    stelle_3 = "2"
    merkmal_hautbild = "fettig"
elif values[2] == "trocken":
    stelle_3 = "3"
    merkmal_hautbild = "trocken"
else: 
    stelle_3 = "undefined"
    merkmal_hautbild = stelle_3
if values[3] == "glossy":
    stelle_4 = "0"
    merkmal_finish = "glossy"
elif values[3] == "matt":
    stelle_4 = "1"
    merkmal_finish = "matt"
else: 
    stelle_4 = "undefined"
    merkmal_finish = stelle_4
    
produktname = stelle_1 + stelle_2 + stelle_3 + stelle_4

layout2 = [[[[sg.Text(("Ihre Angaben:"), expand_y=True)], 
             [sg.Text(("Hautton:"), expand_y=True), sg.Text((merkmal_hautton), expand_y=True)],
             [sg.Text(("Unterton:"), expand_y=True), sg.Text((merkmal_unterton), expand_y=True)],
             [sg.Text(("Hautbild:"), expand_y=True), sg.Text((merkmal_hautbild), expand_y=True)],
             [sg.Text(("Finish:"), expand_y=True), sg.Text((merkmal_finish), expand_y=True)],
             [sg.Text(("Wir empfehlen Ihnen basierend auf Ihren Angaben folgendes Produkt:"), expand_x=True, expand_y=True), sg.Text((produktname), expand_y=True)], 
             [sg.Button(("Erneut durchführen"), expand_x=True, expand_y=True), sg.Button(("Beenden"), expand_x=True, expand_y=True)]]]]
window2 = sg.Window('Empfohlenes Produkt', layout2, size=(550,260))

layout3 = [[[sg.Text(("Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus"), expand_x=True)], 
            sg.Button(("Erneut durchführen"), expand_x=True), sg.Button(("Beenden"), expand_x=True)]]
window3 = sg.Window('Fehler', layout3, size=(450,70))

if event == "Produkt anzeigen":
    if stelle_1 and stelle_2 and stelle_3 and stelle_4 == "undefined":
        window1.disappear()
        event, values = window3.read()
    else:
        window1.disappear()
        event, values = window2.read()
if event == "Erneut durchführen":
    repeat = "Erneut durchführen"
    window1.reappear()
    window3.close()
    window2.close()
elif event == "Beenden":
    window3.close()
    window2.close()
    window1.close()
else:
    window3.close()
    window2.close()
    window1.close()
```

Comment: Something wrong (1) wrong format of layout, should be a list ot rows, and row is list of elements. (2) Should process the window close event first which is None for `event`, so it is not subscriptable. (3) Should call window.read() within each window's event loop to get the event of this window and handle events for different window. Basically, you can create one function for each one window and all of the functions have their own layout, window, event loop, window.read() and event handling, remember to close window before function return.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif event == "Beenden":
    # window3.close()
    window2.close()
    # window1.close()
```

There is no window3 or window1 to close when this event happens.

I used the first 4 options in window1 (so I chose "hell" for option 1) and when window2 pops up, the "Beenden" event triggers window1 and window3 to close (which are not open in my view).

edit:

So you're left with a windowless process running with these two windows commented out